# I fixed a TLS 1.2 issue, but I have no idea how/why it works, or what it's doing? What is this Powershell command doing?

Tags: .net, powershell, ssl, reporting-services, tls1.2

On various Windows 2012 R2 servers, I'm having a TLS issue.

If I run:

```
Install-Module -Name ReportingServicesTools
```

I receive this error (screenshot below)

> WARNING: Unable to download from URI 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
>
> WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.

[image: TLS Error Issue]

If I just put one command above it and run it, it works perfectly. What is it doing and where can I configure it manually in the OS for everything? Somewhere in the GUI/registry/etc?

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 #What is this doing?
Install-Module -Name ReportingServicesTools
```

Comment: Microsoft has documentation on the ServicePointManager class that can help inform you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, this is not a PowerShell specific issue. the [legacy TLS is no longer supported / by web properties/endpoints](https://www.bing.com/search?q=tls%201%20no%20longer%20supported&form=ANSPH1&refig=5df122f9496b49d48d902e36e3b96cd8&sp=-1&pq=tls%201%20no%20longer%20supporte&sc=1-24&qs=n&sk=&cvid=5df122f9496b49d48d902e36e3b96cd8) as announcing a while ago. TLS12 must be used.

> [Solving the TLS 1.0 Problem, 2nd Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/engineering/solving-tls1-problem)
>
> [End of support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1 in Microsoft Cloud App
>   Security](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/enterprise-mobility-security/end-of-support-for-tls-1-0-and-1-1-in-microsoft-cloud-app/ba-p/770507)
>
> GoDaddy [Browsers end support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1 in March 2020](https://www.godaddy.com/garage/browser-support-tls-10-11)
>
> Cisco [End of Life for TLS 1.0/1.1](https://support.umbrella.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033350851-End-of-Life-for-TLS-1-0-1-1-)
>
> As of March 31, 2020, Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.0 and 1.1 will
>   no longer be supported. All endpoints will be required to support TLS
>   1.2 after this date in order to function properly with Cisco Umbrella.
>
> Update: Cisco Umbrella will continue to support Cisco AnyConnect and
>   Cisco Umbrella Roaming Client versions that require TLS 1./0/1.1 until
>   September 30th 2020. All other uses of TLS 1.0 and 1.1 will be
>   discontinued as planned on March 31st.
>
> [TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 Are No Longer Secure](https://www.packetlabs.net/tls-1-1-no-longer-secure)
>
> As of Chrome version 79, released last week, Chrome will start support
>   and start enabling DNS Over HTTPS (DoH), and sites using TLS 1.0 and
>   TLS 1.1 certificates for encryption will be marked as insecure. The
>   marking of sites on TLS 1.0, is significant because 68% of websites
>   still support TLS 1.0 which is insecure due to multiple
>   vulnerabilities. If your web site uses a TLS 1.0 or 1.1 website, as of
>   January 13, 2020 it will display the following warning, and in 2021
>   Chrome will not load websites with TLS 1.0 or 1.1.

So, put that line in all your PowerShell, VSCode profiles and at the top of every script, you have that will ever try and touch any web endpoint.

Comment: Why is it with some servers, I can just run the same command without adding the TLS line? It seems like there's some server parameter that defaults it.

Comment: Correct, it's the settings on the target that cause this use case (no different than web site auth settings, if the site expects SAML Auth you can send it Basic), not PowerShell specifically. For the most part, this is no different than SSL site, which has valid certs and those that don't. Sure, one could always type https://yadda.com, but if the site is not set that way, that https://, does not matter.

Comment: Also, of note. If what we have here addresses your use case, then be sure to make it as your accepted answer, for the benefit of others who find themselves in the same boat.